# Fmtonly on Space in Column Name

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, fmtonly

I have a SP which returns some columns, each column name has space between them like

branch Code
Branch Name (We are assigning alias in our SP)

Now while using fmtonly off I get the column name as returned by the SP, but when I set fmtonly to on it remove the spaces between Column name.

Is it possible to get the same column name returned by SP while setting fmtonly to on?

Thanks

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Im using Sql Server 2008 R2

Comment: [Edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21788/how-does-editing-work) your stored procedure into your question. Also, why do you want to use `SET FMTONLY ON`... what are your specific requirements to do that?

Comment: My SP is way to long but just to give you a hint

select schema_id as 'schema id' from sys.tables

Also I cannot change the SP

Comment: Well, we don't need your exact SP, but please try to create a [mcve] and [edit] that into your question (because code in comments is unreadable, whereas in the question, you can highlight code blocks and hit `{}` and we get readable code with syntax highlighting)